# 401 error when using Spring Security for a CAS client

Tags: spring, tomcat, spring-security, cas

With the setting below, I get the following Tomcat error:

```
  HTTP Status 401 - Authentication Failed: cmccormick
  type Status report
  message Authentication Failed: cmccormick
  description This request requires HTTP authentication.
```

I've also tried protecting the app with SSL, including the url requiring authentication and that resulted in the same error ([approach I used](http://www.captaindebug.com/2012/12/securing-your-tomcat-app-with-ssl-and.html#.U5dFxfldXUY)).

The applicationSecurityContext.xml file (minus the xml header and schema, which SO isn't displaying correctly):

```
<security:http entry-point-ref="casEntryPoint" use-expressions="true" auto-config="false">
    <security:anonymous username="guest" granted-authority="ANONYMOUS"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/resources/**" access="hasAnyRole('ANONYMOUS', 'cm_user')"/>
    <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasRole('cm_user')"/> 
    <security:custom-filter position="CAS_FILTER" ref="casFilter"/>

    <security:session-management>
        <security:concurrency-control max-sessions="5" error-if-maximum-exceeded="true"/>
   </security:session-management>
   <!--  <security:logout logout-url="/j_spring_security_logout" logout-success-url="/home" /> -->
</security:http>

<!-- Base URL for the onboarder application. Used for generating links in outgoing emails -->
<bean id="winauthDomain" class="java.lang.String">
    <!-- Property obtained from deploytime.properties -->
    <constructor-arg value="${winauthDomain}"/>
</bean>

<security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
    <security:authentication-provider ref="casAuthenticationProvider" />
</security:authentication-manager>

<bean id="serviceProperties"
  class="org.springframework.security.cas.ServiceProperties">
  <property name="service"
      value="http://localhost:18080/connmgr/app/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
  <property name="sendRenew" value="false"/>
</bean>

<!-- The CAS filter handles the redirect from the CAS server and starts 
the ticket validation. -->
<bean id="casFilter"
    class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationFilter">
    <property name="authenticationManager" ref="authenticationManager"/>
    <property name="filterProcessesUrl" value="/app/j_spring_cas_security_check"/>
</bean>

<bean id="casEntryPoint"
  class="org.springframework.security.cas.web.CasAuthenticationEntryPoint">
  <property name="loginUrl" value="https://mcauth01.nexus.commercehub.com:5443/login"/>
  <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties"/>
</bean>

  <bean id="casAuthenticationProvider"
      class="org.springframework.security.cas.authentication.CasAuthenticationProvider">
      <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService"/>
      <property name="serviceProperties" ref="serviceProperties" />
      <property name="ticketValidator">
        <bean class="org.jasig.cas.client.validation.Cas20ServiceTicketValidator">
          <constructor-arg index="0" value="https://mcauth01.nexus.commercehub.com:5443" />
        </bean>
  </property>
  <property name="key" value="an_id_for_this_auth_provider_only"/>
</bean>

<bean id="permissionConversionService"
    class="com.commercehub.connmgmt.misc.security.PermissionConversionServiceImpl"/>

<bean id="userDetailsService"
    class="com.commercehub.connmgmt.misc.security.CmUserDetailsService">
    <property name="userRepository" ref="userRepository"/>
    <property name="permissionConversionService" ref="permissionConversionService"/>
</bean>

<bean id="accessDecisionManager" 
        class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.AffirmativeBased">
    <property name="allowIfAllAbstainDecisions">
        <value>false</value>
    </property>
    <property name="decisionVoters">
        <list>
           <ref bean="roleVoter"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="roleVoter" class="org.springframework.security.access.vote.RoleVoter">
    <property name="rolePrefix" value=""/>
</bean>

<!-- 
    This bean automatically receives AuthenticationEvent messages 
    from DaoAuthenticationProvider 
-->
<bean id="loggerListener" 
    class="org.springframework.security.access.event.LoggerListener"/>

<!-- Enable JSR250 annotations, disable Spring Security annotations for now -->
<security:global-method-security secured-annotations="disabled" 
    jsr250-annotations="enabled" 
    access-decision-manager-ref="accessDecisionManager"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the problem was that the legacy config specified a role for the protected url (which is also https now). Those aren't available because authentication goes through CAS.

Incorrect:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="hasRole('cm_user')"/>
```

Correct:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/app/**" access="isAuthenticated()" requires-channel="https"/>
```